# Debug Assertion Failed Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm very new to C++ and I was trying to write a simple program to ask for a person's name then print it back to them. When I did the exact same program with an int type variable, it worked fine. When I replaced it with the string type however, it gave me a "Debug Assertion Failed!" message after I entered my name.
Here is the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(string name)
{
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl << "Your name is " << name << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can you guys point me in the right direction as to why this would fail? I can't seem to find a relevant thread elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: `int main(string name)` isn't valid c++. Change that to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and create a local variable `std::string name;`.

Comment: Aside from the actual problem with your code, "Debug Assertion Failed" messages always have extra information with them. It might not mean anything to you (because you're new to C++), but it _is_ useful and important. Please include it in your question. Note that you can press Ctrl+C to copy Windows message boxes to the clipboard.

Comment: `main` is not overloaded to take a `std::string` as one parameter. instead pass your character string in `argv[1]` or 2..  then assign it to a local string variable or use it directly

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am still wondering why it is a 'debug assertion' rather than a hard link error...

Comment: @SergeyA `main()` accepts almost any parameter declarations without a linker error, because the parameter interpretation is done from the startup code. The `main` entry point is merely an assembly symbol.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes, you are very correct. `main` is undecorated, I totally forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it's C++, the definition of `main` is still in the form of:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Not `int main(string)`.

Fix (since `name` is an output in your program): declare `name` as a local variable

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string name;
```